# Can gzip compress data without loading it all into memory, i.e. streaming/on-the-fly?

Tags: python, compression, gzip

Is it possible to gzip data via some amount of streaming, i.e. without loading all of the compressed data in memory at once?

For example, can I gzip a file that will be 10gb gzipped, on a machine with 2gb of memory?

At https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html#gzip.compress, the `gzip.compress` function returns the bytes of the gzip, so must be all loaded in memory. But... it's not clear how `gzip.open` works internally: whether the zipped bytes will all be in memory at once. Does the gzip format itself make it particularly tricky to achieve a streaming gzip?

[This question is tagged with Python, but non-Python answers welcome as well]

Comment: No, gzip doesn't need to load everything. It was designed to work as a stream. The object returned by `gzip.open()` is a generator that returns the data as needed.

Comment: @Barmar "returns the data": to confirm, I'm not asking about decompressing (I'm fairly sure gzip _can_ decompress in streaming way), but about compressing.

Comment: Don't use the `compress()` or `decompress()` methods. Using `gzip.open()` with `mode='w'` will write to the compressed file. You can also use the underlying `GzipFile()` class to write to any file object.

Comment: Or you can use `compress()`, but you don't have to compress everything at once. You can read the file in blocks, and compress each block separately. But you may not get as good compression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This is based on [@Barmar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65435260/1319998) and comments]

You *can* achieve streaming gzip compression. The [gzip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html) module uses [zlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zlib.html) which is documented to achieve streaming compression, and peeking into the [gzip module source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/gzip.py), it doesn't appear to load all the output bytes into memory.

You can also do this directly with the zlib module, for example with a small pipeline of generators:

```
import zlib

def yield_uncompressed_bytes():
    # In a real case, would yield bytes pulled from the filesystem or the network
    chunk = b'*' * 65000
    for _ in range(0, 10000):
        print('In: ', len(chunk))
        yield chunk

def yield_compressed_bytes(_uncompressed_bytes):
    compress_obj = zlib.compressobj(wbits=zlib.MAX_WBITS + 16)
    for chunk in _uncompressed_bytes:
        if compressed_bytes := compress_obj.compress(chunk):
            yield compressed_bytes

    if compressed_bytes := compress_obj.flush():
        yield compressed_bytes

uncompressed_bytes = yield_uncompressed_bytes()
compressed_bytes = yield_compressed_bytes(uncompressed_bytes)

for chunk in compressed_bytes:
    # In a real case, could save to the filesystem, or send over the network
    print('Out:', len(chunk))
```

You can see that the `In:` are interspersed with the `Out:`, suggesting that the zlib compressobj is indeed not storing the whole output in memory.

Comment: I tried writing chunks to a file, but the result was not recognized as an archive. Here's the code that I used: https://gist.github.com/egor83/b477dc891ef01a0df36ac63f96040f67

Comment: @egor83 You're right - I've now edited the answer to include passing `wbits=zlib.MAX_WBITS + 16` to `zlib.compressobj` that should make it recognised as gzip

Answer (score 7):

You don't have to compress all 10gb at once. You can read the input data in chunks, and compress each chunk separately, so it doesn't have to all fit in memory at once.

```
chunksize = 100 * 1024 * 1024 # 100 mb chunks
with open("bigfile.txt") as infile:
    while True:
        chunk = infile.read(chunksize)
        if not chunk:
            break
        compressed = gzip.compress(chunk)
        # do something with compressed
```

If you're creating a compressed file, you can write the chunks directly to the gzip file.

```
with open("bigfile.txt") as infile, gzip.open("bigfile.txt.gz", "w") as gzipfile:
    while True:
        chunk = infile.read(chunksize)
        if not chunk:
            break
        gzipfile.write(chunk)
```

Comment: Would the concatenation of the chunks still be a valid gzip, so a client could decompress them without knowledge of how they were compressed?

Comment: I think it would be, but I'm not sure. Try it and see.

Comment: Another thing to check out: [`zlip.compressobj`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zlib.html#zlib.compressobj)

Comment: Ah zlib looks like exactly what I want! (Something documented to avoid loading the whole thing into memory). Thank you

Comment: Ah, although I see the gzip module uses zlib internally